# Как отправить emal с помощью php из docker контейнера?

Tags: php, docker, email

Как можно отправить email из докер контейнера? Я смог найти только варианты с локальным smtp сервером для тестов. Есть ли что-то подобное, но с возможностью отправить реальный email? Что бы хотя бы в спам попадал

Answer (score 0):

Используйте yandex smtp или же возможно пригодится https://mailtrap.io/, он письма до конечного адресата не будет доставлять, но в личном кабинете вы можете посмотреть письмо/убедиться что оно ушло с вашего сервера.